# Submatrix incorrectly defined in Scilab

Tags: submatrix

I am given a morse potential to solve and to find its energy eigen values and vector by scilab. But i am having an issue as scilab is saying submatrix defined incorrectly.

I am trying to see why my matrix is unable to be correct. I am new to this platform.

```
De=4.618;

b=18.118;

x=0.1275;

a=0.35;

hc=197.327;

mu=912847000;

N=45;

c=(De/(2*a*b));

d=exp(2*b*(x-a));

e=exp(2*b*x);

i=exp(b*x);

f=(2*De/(a*b));

g=((a*b)^(2));

h=(De*a*b/(2));

  h=zeros(N,N);

  s=eye(N,N);

  for n=1:N

      h(n,n)=(((n*%pi*hc)^2)/(2*mu*a^(2)))+De-(c*d)+(c*e)+(f*d)-(f*e)-((h*(e-d))/(g+(%pi^(2)*n^(2))))+4*((h*(e-d))/(g+(4*(%pi^(2)*n^(2)))));

      for m=n+1:N

          h(m,n)=4*h*(1-(exp(-2*b*a)*((-1)^(m+n))))*e*((1/(4*g+(((m-n)^(2))*%pi^2)))-(1/(4*g+(((m+n)^(2))*%pi^2))))+4*h*i*(1-(exp(-1*b*a)*((-1)^(m+n))))*e*((1/(g+(((m+n)^(2))*%pi^2)))-(1/(g+(((m-n)^(2))*%pi^2))))

          h(n,m)=h(m,n);

          end

  end

  [al,bl,R]=spec(h,s);

  el=al./bl;

  e=R;

  [el,k]=gsort(el)

  disp(h);

  disp(el)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the name `h` for two different variables (a scalar and a matrix), that's why the computation fails. BTW, you are using many useless parenthesis (it does not help to read your code). You can safely replace `h` by capital `H` each time you refer to the matrix after and including the line where you define it:

```
  H=zeros(N,N);
  s=eye(N,N);

  for n=1:N

      H(n,n)=(((n*%pi*hc)^2)/(2*mu*a^(2)))+De-(c*d)+(c*e)+(f*d)-(f*e)-((h*(e-d))/(g+(%pi^(2)*n^(2))))+4*((h*(e-d))/(g+(4*(%pi^(2)*n^(2)))));

      for m=n+1:N

          H(m,n)=4*h*(1-(exp(-2*b*a)*((-1)^(m+n))))*e*((1/(4*g+(((m-n)^(2))*%pi^2)))-(1/(4*g+(((m+n)^(2))*%pi^2))))+4*h*i*(1-(exp(-1*b*a)*((-1)^(m+n))))*e*((1/(g+(((m+n)^(2))*%pi^2)))-(1/(g+(((m-n)^(2))*%pi^2))))

          H(n,m)=H(m,n);

      end

  end

  [al,bl,R]=spec(H,s);
  el=al./bl;
  e=R;
  [el,k]=gsort(el)

  disp(H);

  disp(el)
```

Comment: ohhh yes i was using two variables that was the problem. I didn't checked that mistake.Now the code is working.Thanks