# Round-off error detected, the requested tolerance (or default) cannot be achieved. Try using bigger tolerances in SCILAB

Tags: rounding-error

I am using integrate command but the scilab is showing me round off error detected and saying me to use high tolerance value which i have no clue.

```
a=4
b1=1
b2=3
N=6
v=-50
for n=1:N
    h(n,n)=n^2+(v/a)*integrate('1-cos(2*n*%pi*(r/a))','r',b1,b2)
    for m=n+1:N
        h(m,n)=(v/a)*integrate('(cos((m-n)*%pi*(r/a))-cos((m+n)*%pi*(r/a)))','r',b1,b2)
        h(n,m)=h(m,n)
    end
end

[al,bl,R]=spec(h,s);
el=al./bl;
e=R;
[el,k]=gsort(el)
disp(h);
disp(el)
```

Comment: Before asking a new question can you validate the answer you had for the previous one ? Then I will answer this new one...

Comment: @StéphaneMottelet i had the same problem.

Comment: You have to read, test and validate the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57815134/submatrix-incorrectly-defined-in-scilab

Comment: @StéphaneMottelet Sorry for that. I did it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default absolute tolerance of `integrate` may be too stringent in some cases. Below I changed it to `1e-13` in last argument of `integrate` at line 9 of your script, which now runs fine (I also added the definition of matrix `s` which I supposed to be the identity matrix, like in your previous message):

```
a=4
b1=1
b2=3
N=6
v=-50
for n=1:N
    h(n,n)=n^2+(v/a)*integrate('1-cos(2*n*%pi*(r/a))','r',b1,b2)
    for m=n+1:N
        h(m,n)=(v/a)*integrate('(cos((m-n)*%pi*(r/a))-cos((m+n)*%pi*(r/a)))','r',b1,b2,1e-13)
        h(n,m)=h(m,n)
    end
end

s=eye(N,N);
[al,bl,R]=spec(h,s);
el=al./bl;
e=R;
[el,k]=gsort(el)
disp(h);
disp(el)
```

Comment: checking on to it.I also have no idea why this factor came aside as  my job was just to see the physics behind (sorry didnt said earlier it is a finite 1D square well problem) and the wave function and our professor taught us few things of the scilab syntax. So i am confused what is this tolarance about and why only this value is taken?

Comment: Thanks its working now. But please do help me when to add the factor you added in integrate command and when to not and what actually it does it?

Comment: The `integrate` function uses an adaptive integration scheme and adjusts the length of integration step w.r.t. to an estimation of integration error. The `rtol` and `atol` optional parameters (see the help page of `integrate`) allow to change the relative and absolute tolerance which is compared to this estimation. Depending on the function to integrate, the default values have sometimes to be increased.